# Getting data from Array[String] in RDD using Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an Array[String] of the form:

```
res3: Array[String] =
Array("{{Infobox officeholder
|name=Abraham Lincoln
|image=Abraham Lincoln November 1863.jpg{{!}}border
|term_start=March 4, 1861
|term_end=April 15, 1865
|term_start2=March 4, 1847,
"{{Infobox officeholder
|name=Mickael Jackson
|term_start=April 9, 1991
|term_end=April 15, 1865
|term_start2=March 4, 1847")
```

Now, what I need is to create an Array of the form:

```
("Abraham Lincoln: March 4, 1861",
"Michael Jackson: April 9, 1991",
...
```

But, i.e. term_start is not always in the same index within the array. So, I need some way of do it using regex or contains for each line.
Is there any way of do it using scala? The data is load from a bz2 file and then converted to this way.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post how `rdd.take(5)` looks like? The string looks weird.

Comment: `res3: Array[String] =
Array("{{Infobox officeholder
|name=Abraham Lincoln
|predecessor=[[James Buchanan]]
|successor=[[Andrew Johnson]]
|office2=Member of the [[U.S. House of Representatives]] from [[Illinois]]'s [[Illinois' 7th congressional district|7th]] district
|district2=
|term_start2=March 4, 1847
|term_en...
` and the name of the key is the same in some cases, Im only interested in concatenate the value of the name and the value of the birth_date...

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your output format, but maybe this example using dataframes can help you to solve your problem:

```
case class Message(text: String)

val iterations: (String => Array[String]) = (input: String) => {
  input.split('|')
}
val udf_iterations = udf(iterations)

val transformation: (String => String) = (input: String) => {
  input.split("=")(1).trim + ": " + input.split("=")(0).trim
}
val udf_transformation = udf(transformation)

val p1 = Message("AAA=valAAA1 | BBB=valBBB1 | CCC=valCCC1")
val p2 = Message("ZZZ=valZZZ2 | AAA=valAAA2 | BBB=valBBB2")

val records = Seq(p1, p2)
val df = spark.createDataFrame(records)

df.withColumn("text-explode", explode(udf_iterations(col("text"))))
  .withColumn("text-transformed", udf_transformation(col("text-explode")))
  .show(false)

+---------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+
|text                                   |text-explode |text-transformed|
+---------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+
|AAA=valAAA1 | BBB=valBBB1 | CCC=valCCC1|AAA=valAAA1  |valAAA1: AAA    |
|AAA=valAAA1 | BBB=valBBB1 | CCC=valCCC1| BBB=valBBB1 |valBBB1: BBB    |
|AAA=valAAA1 | BBB=valBBB1 | CCC=valCCC1| CCC=valCCC1 |valCCC1: CCC    |
|ZZZ=valZZZ2 | AAA=valAAA2 | BBB=valBBB2|ZZZ=valZZZ2  |valZZZ2: ZZZ    |
|ZZZ=valZZZ2 | AAA=valAAA2 | BBB=valBBB2| AAA=valAAA2 |valAAA2: AAA    |
|ZZZ=valZZZ2 | AAA=valAAA2 | BBB=valBBB2| BBB=valBBB2 |valBBB2: BBB    |
+---------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+
```